# ¿Cómo obtener los 5 años atrás del año actual en sql oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Quiero que me devuelva los 5 años atrás del año actual (que sea dinámico) en SQL Oracle:

Quiero que me devuelva así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intentaste algo?

Comment: Esto lo quieres obtener desde una tabla o generarla _al vuelo_?

Comment: Quiero generar a partir del sysdate

Comment: Podrías agregar código para ver que has intentado. Igual ya te damos algunas ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes valerte de un CTE para construir esta información al vuelo. Una forma sencilla de hacerlo es extraer el año de la fecha actual y unirlo las veces que sea necesario mientras le vamos restando valores al año.

En código, se vería algo así:

```
with  
Anios as ( 
          select extract(year from sysdate) anio from dual 
union all select extract(year from sysdate) - 1 from dual 
union all select extract(year from sysdate) - 2 from dual 
union all select extract(year from sysdate) - 3 from dual 
union all select extract(year from sysdate) - 4 from dual 
) 
select * 
  from Anios
```

Lo cual, al ejecutarlo hoy, me devuelve:

```
ANIO
====
2019
2018
2017
2016
2015
```

Puedes probar el script en vivo [aquí](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/ikt5tt3bbb78hcrlvilkobbbr).

Comment: Y para que necesitas el CTE ahi? si con el union lo hace :/

Answer (score 1):

Usando cualquier tabla que tenga mas de 5 registros en tu base de datos, podes hacer lo siguiente:

```
select extract(year from sysdate) - (rownum-1) anio from una_tabla_cualquiera
where rownum < 6 order by anio
```

De esta forma, podrias hasta parametrizar la cantidad de registros que podes pedir.